# Connecting Android Emulator in my Local System(Personal PC - Windows) and running the Appium test cases from the Remote Desktop(Windows)

Tags: android, debugging, networking, appium, remote-desktop

First of all I would like to thank you for efforts to help. The issue I am facing is described below.

I have installed Android SDK Arctic Fox in my personal PC and set up Emulator to perform automation using appium. I have to keep my framework code and the apk of the app under test, in a remote desktop / virtual machine in cloud. I have installed the SDK in the cloud VM, but I can't establish a connection between the  **adb in the Cloud VM**  and the the **locally installed emulator**. When I tried to use *"adb connect 192.168.1.4:5585"*  command I am getting an error like **`"cannot connect to 192.168.1.4:5585: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060)"`**. Can anyone help me to sort out this issue, to **connect an Android Emulator** running on physical device with a **cloud VM**.
Also if some one can inform a good **Port forwarding Software** it will be helpful. I have a windows PC. 
I am not really aware of networking concepts and setting up android, so please bear me if I have done some mistakes in the steps followed. It will be really helpful if any one can help me on this and explain the mistakes I did and the how to enable this connection. Please let me know if I need to elaborate further.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot reach you local pc as 192.168.1.4 is not part of the cloud's network. Try using a service like https://dyndns.org/ to find your pc from your cloud vm, as a public host.

Therefore, instead of using 192.168.1.4:5585 from you cloud, you will be using something like HomePcPublicHostName:5585.